# Basemap cannot find basemap-data-hires

Tags: python, conda, matplotlib-basemap

I need to draw maps in High resolution in python. Basemap and `basemap-data-hires` are both installed, but basemap does not find the `basemap-data-hires`.

Both are installed as you can see from this conda list:

```
    packages in environment at /home/paloma/anaconda3/envs/PAG2019:

    Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    basemap                   1.2.0            py36h705c2d8_0    anaconda
    basemap-data-hires        1.2.0                         0    conda-forge
    gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1    anaconda
```

Suspecting a conflicting/wrong installation, I tried to re-install `basemap-data-hires` from anaconda and conda-forge, but to no avail.

Here is the import I use: 
    `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

Here is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./MakeGraphs.py", line 89, in <module>
    lat_ts=0.5*(lats[0,0]+lats[-1,-1]),lat_0=0.5*(lats[0,0]+lats[-1,-1]),lon_0=0.5*(lons[0,0]+lons[-1,-1]))
  File "/home/paloma/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 1122, in __init__
    self._readboundarydata('gshhs',as_polygons=True)
  File "/home/paloma/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 1236, in _readboundarydata
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Unable to open boundary dataset file. Only the 'crude' and  'low',
resolution datasets are installed by default.
If you are requesting an, 'intermediate', 'high' or 'full'
resolution dataset, you may need to download and install those
files separately with
`conda install basemap-data-hires`.
```

Any idea anyone??

---

On closer look, there's probably a conflict between the CONDA_PREFIX of the environment:

```
$CONDA_PREFIX=/home/paloma/anaconda3/envs/PAG2019
```

and the basemap_datadir of basemap:

```
basemap_datadir=/home/paloma/anaconda3/
```

Does some know how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

For installing 'intermediate', 'high' or 'full' use the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

Otherwise you will have 'crude' and 'low' only, installed by default.

Comment: Thanks. but basemap-data-hires is already installed, as you can see from the conda list.

Comment: Yes but only 'crude' and 'low', if you want  'intermediate', 'high' or 'full' resolution use this. Else change your code for low resolution.

Comment: try to install mamba as replacement to conda. Surely you will be surprised to the download speed..such an amazing. I have migrated to the method now

Answer (score 0):

As basemap went to look for the files in the directory of the base environment, installing basemap-data-hires in the *base* worked for me.

Quick and dirty, but effective.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, this page recommended trying one of the three options:

https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/basemap-data-hires

```
> conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires conda install -c
> conda-forge/label/cf201901" basemap-data-hires conda install -c
> conda-forge/label/cf202003" basemap-data-hires
```

The third line worked for me, first one didn't.